# ICommand.Execute Method (Object)

Tags: c#, android, navigation, mvvmcross, execute

If I dot Execute with a parameter from my View

`GoToNextScreen.Execute(selectedSubMenuIndex);`

and this calls a method in my ViewModel

```
        private MvxCommand _goSecondCommand;
        public IMvxCommand GoSecondCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _goSecondCommand = _goSecondCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoGoSecond);
                return _goSecondCommand;

                //try to call a command that navigates
            }
        }

        public void DoGoSecond()
        {
            ShowViewModel<OnlineGroceryShoppingViewModel>(); //action to go to the second view
        }
```

but it jumps straight to DoGoSecond when I step through, how can I access the passed parameter, selectedSubMenuIndex, in the DoGoSecond Method?

PS,
I have

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
set.Bind(this).For(v => v.GoToNextScreen).To(vm => vm.GoSecondCommand);
set.Apply();
```

so GoToNextScreen calls GoSecondCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the generic version of `MvxCommand`:

```
private MvxCommand<int> _goToSecondCommand;
public ICommand GoToSecondCommand =>
    _goToSecondCommand = _goToSecondCommand ?? new MvxCommand<int>(DoGoToSecond);

private void DoGoToSecond(int index)
{
    // do stuff with index
}
```

You could then pass that index along to your `OnlineGroceryShoppingViewModel`:

```
ShowViewModel<OnlineGroceryShoppingViewModel>(new { index = index });
```

Then get it in `OnlineGroceryShoppingViewModel` in the `Init` method:

```
public void Init(int index)
{
    // do stuff based on index
}
```

Comment: u r my hero! I've seen your comments on Xamarin Forums, how do I become as wise as you?  Thanks again!

Comment: Wax on, wax off